# R - Concatenate integer arrays

Tags: r

How can I join `1:3` and `7:8` to `1 2 3 7 8`?

Where is a good resource to pick up peculiars like this?

Comment: http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-intro.pdf

Comment: wow, is it that bad that I should just delete it?

Comment: I don't think it's such a terrible question, but the lightest reading of a The Introduction to R would get you as far as how to use c() - section 2.1 page 7, so it's a bit simple. Please do read it.

Comment: indeed, just reading a couple of chapters of the introduction or reading `help(c)` would have given the answer here. So, this is a bad question in that sense. OTOH, in practice, I had never seen a use of `c` with a sort of nesting, always flat usage like `c(1, 2, 5)`. Coming from other languages, it's somewhat remarkable that `c(c("1", "2", c("X")), "3", 1:5)` is possible with this builtin. Oh well, if someone googles this they have a quick answer now.

Comment: lol, popular question badge.

Comment: lol, notable question badge.

Comment: Still, after 5 years only 1 up-vote. I gave you a second. ;)

Comment: That's like 10 upvotes and 8 downsides lol.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
c(1:3, 7:8)
[1] 1 2 3 7 8
```

The help page indicates `this is a generic function which combines its arguments.`

Comment: Thank you. I'm teaching myself here; some things are hard to search.

Comment: No worries - I find myself recommending [this wiki](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/vocabulary) often for these sorts of things. Check it out.

Comment: The [R reference card](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Short-refcard.pdf) is fairly nice too.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this as well:

```
 v<-c(1:3)
 v<-c(v, 7:8)
```